# Python - adjust width automaticaly in excel file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I wouldlike to adjust the width of my excel file automatically. I don't know if it is possible ?
I use this code to display data in my file :

```
def create_rapport(self, name_file, data,  column_name, all_intersection):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name_file[:-4] + ".xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=data.keys(), columns=column_name)
    df.to_excel(writer)
    print(df)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: you want to set column width or excel??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to autofit all of the columns automatically, then you will need to use the win32com interface as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'file.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Columns.AutoFit()
wb.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

This can easily be done after you closed the file using your current xlsxwriter code. Note, you might need to supply a full path to your file.